# Javascript Input Validation For Preventing URLS in TextBox

Tags: javascript, validation, input

I already have the below code for making sure the text box area is not empty. I would like to add another code that would not allow the form to be submitted if the person enters urls. For example, I want http to be blocked.  I have tried to figure out how to do this, but I have been unsuccessful.

Here's my code for making sure the textbox area is not empty. Please copy and paste it and help me to figure out how to add another condition that does not allow the form to be submitted if there is http.

```
        
    if (document.frmMailingList.txtaKnowledge.value == "")
    {
        alert("Please include how you heard about us!");
        document.frmMailingList.txtaKnowledge.focus();
        return false;
    }
```

I have not been able to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to try and parse the text into a url, and if it throws an error, then you know it is not a valid url.

```
var isUrl = true;
try {
    new URL(document.frmMailingList.txtaKnowledge.value)
} catch(error) {
    isUrl = false
}

if (document.frmMailingList.txtaKnowledge.value == "" && !isURL) {
    alert("Please include how you heard about us!");
    document.frmMailingList.txtaKnowledge.focus();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. I am actually looking to not allow any urls at all. I want it to block any content that has http.